# PHP $_FILES Not Working with JQuery Json

Tags: jquery, json, file-upload

I'm building a form with JQuery and PHP and everything seem to work accept the file upload. Json doesn't seem to like the $_FILES. The form uploads fine when javascript is turned off. Is this a known issue? If it is, is there a work around? How do JQuery plugins manage to do this?

Thank you!

JQUERY:

```
$('#mcContactForm').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    // validate form
    mcValidateForm();

    // serialize and submit form data
    $('.mcloading').show();
    var mcFormData = $(this).serialize();
    mcSubmitForm(mcFormData);

    // -----------------------------------------------
    // AJAX FORM SUBMIT
    // -----------------------------------------------
    function mcSubmitForm(mcFormData){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'contact.php',
            data: mcFormData,
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            timeout: 7000,
            success: function(data) {
                if(data.error === true){

                    ...
                }
                else if(data.error === false){

                    ...
                }
            },
            error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(errorThrown);
                ...
            },              
            complete: function(XMLHttpRequest, status) { 
                ...
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Could you show us your code maybe? :) That wourld REALLY help

Comment: I just read that serialize() does not submit file input fields. That is the core of the question. Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: @user1002039, yes, the workaround is to submit to a hidden iframe field instead of using ajax. there are many query plugins that do this for you. see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like maybe you are trying to upload files via ajax and discovering that this can't be done by simply sending the form parameters back via regular ajax? If so, what you need is an ajax file upload plugin. See here for some possibilities:

http://www.webdeveloperjuice.com/2010/02/13/7-trusted-ajax-file-upload-plugins-using-jquery/

These typically use a system of submitting to hidden iframes to do the uploads.

Comment: Thank you! Is there a tutorial on how to do the hidden iframe submission. I'm not even sure what that means. I have nothing against plugins but I'd like to learn how this is done.

Comment: Well hidden iframe submission is not completely simple, that's why I'd recommend a plugin for it. But what it means basically is you create an iframe with "display: none" style (so the user can't see it). And then set the `target` attribute of your form to the name of the frame. This will make it submit *as if* it were in that frame. Then you set up javascript event handlers to catch when the upload is done based on some details in the iframe, and then have the iframe communicate back to the parent to finish the process.

Comment: It's actually kind of a difficult-to-roll-own process even though it is straightforward in concept. A plugin will let you do all that in one line of code though.